# Bootstrap Modal not working via javascript

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am calling a bootstrap modal via a jquery inside of a function for an error message as follows:

```
$('#validateButton').click(function() {

    var registrationLocation = $('#url').val();

    if (registrationLocation.indexOf("http") ==0) {
        // TODO - hardcoded DataFlow - this MUST be fixed!
        var hc06DfUrn = "urn:sdmx:org.sdmx.infomodel.datastructure.Dataflow=ESTAT:HC06(1.0)";
        $.getJSON("/" + webappName + "/ws/rest/registerservice?url=" + registrationLocation + "&dataflowurn="+hc06DfUrn, registerFileSuccess).error(displayErrorDialog);
    } else {
        $.getJSON("/" + webappName + "/ws/rest/registerfile?url=" + registrationLocation, registerFileSuccess).error(displayErrorDialog);
    }
    $('#errorDialog').modal('show')
});
```

Heres my `html` for the modal:

```
<div id="errorDialog" class="modal hide fade">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
        </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body…</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
  </div>
```

I am seeing the fade effect but no modal is appearing when i inspect the html on the page the modal seems to empty:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your markup or the call to the modal.  If you open dev tools and check the Console are you getting any javascript errors when you click the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a DIV for the modal body to be placed (container):

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in" id="myModal">
    <div id="myModalContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Then on button click pass the modal body into the container DIV:

```
$('#validateButton').click(function () {
    var url = "/SomeModal/Url";
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $('#myModalContainer').html(data);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```